# Is it okay to convert an image with an alpha channel to an image without an alpha channel?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am a beginner to Image Processing and I want to know whether it's okay to convert a 4 channel image to a 3 channel image and a 2 channel image to a single channel image for simple image processing applications so that I only have to write code for 3 and single channel images?

Answer (score 1):

99.5% of all image processing algorithms work on one channel only. If you have more channels you usually convert them into one channel.

Like if you have RGB you usually work with R,G,B separately or you convert them into H,S and I. Sometimes you have more complex conversions.

Images from cameras come without alpha channel. Its just something you use to make things transparent for web design and things like that. So besides the design stuff the alpha channel usually bears no information. Of course you are always free to somehow use that alpha channel to make transparent things black in an image that has no alpha channel e.g.

I suggest you get yourself some basic knowledge about colour spaces and image formats befor you continue with image processing. If you understand the basics you can answer such questions to yourself.

Comment: Agreed - especially if the emphasis is *"computer vision"* applications - e.g. object detection/tracking, object recognition. Alpha channels become more important with *"computer graphics"* applications.

Answer (score 0):

This really cannot be answered in general - it depends on your current application.

Usual images like photographs don't come with an alpha channel. If the image has one, you usually want to respect it. Sometimes blending over a single color background will do the job, sometimes it won't work.

Some algorithms work great on B/W images where one channel is the way to go, but then again, others don't.

If you're just "getting your feet wet" with CV, starting with B/W images is a reasonable approach. It just won't work for *all* applications.